# hold time violation during FPGA post place and route simulation in modelsim

Tags: fpga, xilinx, timing, modelsim

I am designing a simple encryption circuit on Xilinx Virtex-5 FPGA. I have given the timing constraint in the UCF as below:

```
NET "clk" TNM_NET = clk;
TIMESPEC TS_clk = PERIOD "clk" 25 ns HIGH 50%;
```

My design does not have any errors in static timing analysis report after place and route. Part of the report is shown below:

```
Timing errors: 0  Score: 0

Constraints cover 191219 paths, 0 nets, and 38438 connections

Design statistics:
   Minimum period:   9.954ns{1}   (Maximum frequency: 100.462MHz)
```

However, when I run a post place and route timing simulation in modelsim. It gives me this error and the design does not generate the proper result in the simulation.

```
# ** Error: /home/rex/opt/Xilinx/10.1/ISE/verilog/mti_se/simprims_ver/simprims_ver_source.v(121020): $hold( posedge CLK:650974 ps, negedge I &&& (in_clk_enable1 != 0):651125 ps, 153 ps );
#    Time: 651125 ps  Iteration: 0  Instance: /tb/aes_wrapper_0/\aes_fwd_0/aes_fwd_core_inst/CIPHER_RND_1_ARK_ROW_1_4_ARK_COL_1_3_xor_itm_1_sg1 
# ** Error: /home/rex/opt/Xilinx/10.1/ISE/verilog/mti_se/simprims_ver/simprims_ver_source.v(121020): $hold( posedge CLK:650974 ps, negedge I &&& (in_clk_enable1 != 0):651125 ps, 153 ps );
#    Time: 651125 ps  Iteration: 0  Instance: /tb/aes_wrapper_0/\aes_fwd_0/aes_fwd_core_inst/CIPHER_RND_1_ARK_ROW_1_4_ARK_COL_1_2_xor_itm_1_sg3_0 
# ** Error: /home/rex/opt/Xilinx/10.1/ISE/verilog/mti_se/simprims_ver/simprims_ver_source.v(121020): $hold( posedge CLK:650974 ps, negedge I &&& (in_clk_enable1 != 0):651125 ps, 153 ps );
#    Time: 651125 ps  Iteration: 0  Instance: /tb/aes_wrapper_0/\aes_fwd_0/aes_fwd_core_inst/CIPHER_RND_1_ARK_ROW_1_4_ARK_COL_1_3_xor_itm_1_sg3_0 
# ** Error: /home/rex/opt/Xilinx/10.1/ISE/verilog/mti_se/simprims_ver/simprims_ver_source.v(121019): $hold( posedge CLK:650974 ps, posedge I &&& (in_clk_enable1 != 0):651125 ps, 153 ps );
#    Time: 651125 ps  Iteration: 0  Instance: /tb/aes_wrapper_0/\aes_fwd_0/aes_fwd_core_inst/CIPHER_RND_1_ARK_ROW_1_4_ARK_COL_1_2_xor_itm_1_sg3_2 
# ** Error: /home/rex/opt/Xilinx/10.1/ISE/verilog/mti_se/simprims_ver/simprims_ver_source.v(121020): $hold( posedge CLK:650974 ps, negedge I &&& (in_clk_enable1 != 0):651125 ps, 153 ps );
#    Time: 651125 ps  Iteration: 0  Instance: /tb/aes_wrapper_0/\aes_fwd_0/aes_fwd_core_inst/CIPHER_RND_1_ARK_ROW_1_4_ARK_COL_1_3_xor_itm_3
```

I only know this is a hold time violation. How do I interpret this error information more precisely? How to solve this problem?

Updates:
I tracked the signals that cause the hold time violation. The input pad is connected to some combinational logic before it goes to the DFF which has hold time violation. I assume adding OFFSET IN constraint will solve this problem. How do I determine the right value (??ns) in the OFFSET IN constraint?

```
OFFSET = IN ??ns BEFORE "clk";
```

Comment: I'd start by upgrading your tools. 10.1 is a good number of versions behind the current 14.4. Since the hold violation was not reported  during synthesis, but modelsim picks it up, there might be an issue with the tools that has been fixed since 10.1

Comment: Do you recognize the register in the error message? Could you put up some code showing any relevant connectivity? Reading [this app note](http://www.xilinx.com/support/answers/5255.htm), it says that "At a minimum, every design should have PERIOD, OFFSET IN, and OFFSET OUT constraints.". I don't know if this applies to you, but might want to read this: http://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/white_papers/wp237.pdf

Comment: yeah but ISE 10.1 was one of their better efforts. For Virtex 5 it's fine. @Rex : trace both source and destination points on a failing signal - it is likely that one or the other is not a regular FF (possibly BRAM, mult or I/O pin). Often you need to add timing constraints to cover I/O signals and special function blocks (BRAM used to need its own constraints)

Comment: Trace where the inputs to this signal come from - if any are external and asynchronous, you *will* see violations.

Comment: @StaceyAnne, I agree with Brian, 10.1 is a major software launch along with Virtex-5 series. The lastest version I tried before is 13.1. I do not find anything particularly more useful.

Comment: @Tim, I tracked the signals and it seems that the data input pad is connected to some combinational logic before it goes to the first DFF which has the hold time violation. I also read the documentation on offset in/out constraints. But how do I determine the exact value of the offset in parameter for my design?

Comment: @Brian Drummond, thank you for the hint. Please see my question above.

Comment: @Martin Thompson, thank you for the hint. I tracked the signals and it seems that the data input pad is connected to some combinational logic before it goes to the first DFF which has the hold time violation. I also read the documentation on offset in/out constraints. But how do I determine the exact value of the offset in parameter for my design?

Comment: @rex - I don't know exactly, but my guess is that your problem is that your data is changing at the same time as the clock, so you get a hold time violation in sim. If your data always changes on the clock edge in the testbench, then maybe set the offset in to some delta greater than the hold time of your flops, maybe 25% of the clock period just as a safe assumption. That way the data will be changing later than the clock edge and won't violate.

Comment: @StaceyAnne, I download Vivado today and they only support 7-series devices...

Comment: I was referring to ISE: http://www.xilinx.com/support/download/index.html/content/xilinx/en/downloadNav/design-tools.html

Comment: why you are choosing 25 ns for clk_period?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't get a violating in timing analysis, but do in simulation, your timing analysis is likely incomplete. Revisit clock crossing and TIG (ignore) in particular. See [Xilinx answer 38348](http://www.xilinx.com/support/answers/34348.htm) for more details on TIG.

Comment: Thank you Brian, I cannot find the word "crossing" or "TIG" in the timing report. Could you elaborate? BTW: What does TIG mean?

Comment: @rex, TIG = timing ignore, it's the keyword for ignoring a particular path in the constraints file.